# Video recorder doesn’t write video in exe format Code:

Tags: python, opencv, webcam

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
# Define the codec and create VideoWriter object fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID') 

out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi',fourcc, 20.0, (640,480)) 

while(cap.isOpened()): 
    ret, frame = cap.read() 
    if ret==True: 
        frame = cv2.flip(frame,0) 
        # write the flipped frame
        out.write(frame) 

cv2.imshow('frame',frame) 
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'): break 
    else: break 
# Release everything if job is finished
cap.release() 
out.release() 
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

It records properly using python but when I convert it using pyinstaller the video produces an output.avi without content (0 byte). I also tried cx_freeze but the result is the same.

Comment: Perhaps cx_freeze didn't package the ffmpeg library with your code?

Comment: in C++ the beahviour occurs, if the opencv_ffmpg dll isn't available to the program